# C++ Having Issues with Fstream and Storing Data into Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

For an assignment I am working on, I am suppose to stream a file and find the distance between two point. In the ifile, there are 6 integers per line. Since each pointdistance has 3 points, I decided to make 2 arrays with the size of 3. However, I am having great difficulty getting the data into the array. Here is a sample of what the ifile looks like.

```
 2     5     2     8     5     2
 9     0     0     1     3     0
 0     8     8     9     6     3
 3     9     1     8     5     2
 1     4    10     0     0     9
 9     8     1     3     6     8
 9    10     7     3     2     5
```

Here is a sample of the code I have been working on.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using std::cout; 
using std::endl; 
using std::sqrt; 
using std::ifstream; 
using std::string; 


namespace roz
{
bool readpoints(ifstream&ifile, int p1[], int p2[], int sz);
static int
pointdistance()
{
    const int coords = 3; 
    int p1[coords]; 
    int p2[coords]; 

    ifstream ifile; 
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Joshbox\\Desktop\\points-3d.txt"; 
    ifile.open(path); 
    if (!ifile) {
        cout << "File not found: " << path << endl; 

        return -1;
    }




    while (readpoints(ifile, p1, p2, coords)) {

    }



    return 0;
}

bool readpoints(ifstream&ifile, int p1[], int p2[], int sz) {
    string data; 
    while (getline(ifile, data)) {
        for (int a = 1; a < sz; a++) {
            ifile >> p1[a]; 
        }

        cout << p1; 
    }

    return true; 
}


static int(*currentAssignment)() = pointdistance; 
int cse()
{
    return currentAssignment();
}
```

}

Comment: Okay... so what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @cdhowie well when I try to cout one of my points, I get a weird output such as: F8CC0093. I been playing with my code over the past 2 days and I can not figure out why this is happening

Comment: `while (getline(ifile, data))` gets the line (numbers you want with spaces) into a string - so you nearly have what you need, but then you do `ifile >> p1[a]; ` - try to use `data` instead. Maybe chuck in a `cout << data << '\n';` just to see what you've read and write a small function to parse that

Comment: @doctorlove Thanks for responding.  When I do cout << data, it correctly displays the data. However, When I try data >> p1[a], it gives me a no operator ">>" matches these operands because It is a string type.

Comment: Exactly - you need to *split* the string on the spaces and turn the strings you get into numbers. Nearly there.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your code.

- `readpoints` always returns true, which means your loop `while (readpoints(ifile, p1, p2, coords))` in the main function never terminates.
- The `readpoints` function is completely wrong.

  - You're storing a whole line into `data` and then never using it, which means this code only actually acts upon half the lines, discarding every alternate line starting with the first one.
  - `for (int a = 1; a < sz; a++)` is going to read one-less-than the number input to iterate over, and since the number you're passing in is '3', you're only going to read 2. Starting index should be '0', not '1'.
  - `cout << p1` is going to print the address of the array, not the contents of the array. If you're expecting this code to print the contents of your array, you need to manually iterate over `p1` with a construct like `for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) cout << p1[i] << ' ';`

There's also a few other things you could be doing differently, though these are more "best practices" and not "reasons why your code is failing".

- Your rampant use of `using std::*` is making your code difficult to read. Though you haven't made the bigger, more common mistake (where people write `using namespace std;`), you generally shouldn't do this unless you have long, cumbersome namespace tokens, and `std` doesn't qualify for "long and cumbersome".
- `int p1[coords];`: Don't use C-style arrays. In C++-land, the preferred syntax for expressing a stack-allocated array is `std::array<int, coords> p1;`. When you pass these arrays to your functions, write the signature like `bool readpoints(ifstream & ifile, std::array<int, coords> & p1, std::array<int, coords> & p2);`. Because arrays can query their own size, you don't need to specify the size manually, and because arrays allow for use of iterators, you can write code like this: `for(int & val : p1) ifile >> val;` `for(int & val : p2) ifile >> val;`

Comment: Another benefit to using `std::array` is we can use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` along with the many useful functions in `<algorithm>` to vastly simplify many other things in this program.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. I am still confused though. My professor last semester told us arrays are evil and don't use them, so I don't have much experience/knowledge of using arrays. I am re-reading the comments/answers, but conceptually it is just not clicking. I watched countless videos on fstream and still nothing. I'm starting to think coding is not for me

Comment: Another recommendation is to use `std::vector<int>` instead of array.

Comment: @jrooz Your professor was likely intending to give the same advice I did, which is that "C-Style arrays (declared like `int arr[5];`) are evil, and the 'non-evil' way to express the same concept is `std::array<int, 5> arr;`". If what they meant was "stack-allocated arrays are evil", then you probably want something like `std::vector<int>`, which allocate arrays in dynamic memory and (if used correctly) resize the dynamic memory as needed.

Comment: @Xirema I really appreciate the time taken to help me out, I'll let you guys know if I figure it out. I feel like I'm having a stroke though, but I won't give up.

Comment: @Xirema after a few hours, i figure out how to do the problem properly. Thanks for the suggestions!